# Linux I2C file handles - safe to cache?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, i2c

I am just starting to look at the I2C support on (embedded) linux (Beaglebone Black, to be precise). Since it's linux, everything is a file, so it's no surprise that I2C is too.

```
int file = open( "/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR );
```

and then the actual address on that bus is selected through `ioctl()`. My question is this - is it safe, or even *legal*, to cache `file` for the duration of application execution? It would seem to my naive eyes that the overheading of opening a resource to read every 250ms would be an unnecessary strain on the kernel. So it is valid to open, and then just use `ioctl()` to switch address whenever I need to, or must I `close()` the descriptor between reads and writes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it safe, or even legal, to cache `file` for the duration of application execution?

The file descriptor (that is returned from open()) is valid for as long as your program needs to keep executing.

Device nodes in /dev may resemble filenames, but they are treated differently from filesystem entries once you look past the syscall interface.  An open() or read() on a file descriptor for a device will invoke the device driver, whereas for an actual file its filesystem is invoked, which may eventually call a storage device driver.

> It would seem to my naive eyes that the overheading of opening a resource to read every 250ms would be an unnecessary strain on the kernel.

Yes it would since those open() and close() syscalls are unnecessary.

> So it is valid to open, and then just use ioctl() to switch address whenever I need to,

Yes, that is the proper useage.

> or must I close() the descriptor between reads and writes?

That is not necessary nor advised.